# Scala enumeration map implementation

Tags: java, scala

Java has [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) - special `Map` implementation designed for the case when keys are of `enum` type (Please, see class declaration `EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V>`). The main advantage over, for instance, `java.util.HashMap` is the memory and performance efficiency, because it knows number of keys in advance, because they declared in enumeration, so it is memory compact and faster, because there is no need to extend internal table and resolve hash conflicts.

I'm wondering is there any Scala implementation out of the box for this Java implementation, but with Scala's `Enumeration` and `immutable.Map` interface. Maybe any external lib implementation or any way to create own implementation with close memory and performance results?

Thank you so much for a help in advance!

Comment: Informative benchmark at https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum/issues/113#issuecomment-277724787

Comment: @MarioGalic oh wow, thank you so much for pointing me to this. Please, answer this question with the link you provided, so I can up-vote and accept it! Thank you.

Comment: Scala also has special implementations for small immutable maps (containing up to 4 elements), so these are already quite efficient: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L222

Comment: @StephaneBersier Thank you for your comment. Excuse me, please, maybe I missing something, but `EmptyMap` is just special implementation for empty map, as name stands. Maybe you pointer you wanted to point to another implementation, not that one?

Comment: @IvanKurchenko if you keep reading past the definition of `EmptyMap`, you will see the definitions of `Map1`, `Map2`, `Map3` and `Map4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumeratum's open issue [EnumSet/EnumMap #113](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum/issues/113#issuecomment-277724787) gives an informative benchmark

```
[info] MapComparisons.enumeratumScalaMapGet       avgt   30   9.830 ± 0.207  ns/op
[info] MapComparisons.jEnumEnumMapGet             avgt   30   4.745 ± 0.685  ns/op
[info] MapComparisons.jEnumScalaMapGet            avgt   30  12.204 ± 0.186  ns/op
```

where lloydmeta [states](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum/pull/114)

> So the current state of things is that Java EnumMap and EnumSet are
>   roughly 2x faster than plain old Scala Set and Maps w/ Enumeratum, but
>   being that we're still in the sub-10ns range, it seems reasonable to
>   say that performance here won't be a bottleneck except in super edge
>   cases.

I tried to replicate lloydmeta's benchmarks and got the following results with Scala 2.13, enumeratum 1.5.15

```
sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 10 -f 2 -t 1 -prof gc bench.So60374058"
```

**Average time, time/op**

```
enumeratumScalaMapGet   avgt   20     8.284 ±   0.071   ns/op
jEnumEnumMapGet         avgt   20     2.883 ±   0.023   ns/op
jEnumScalaMapGet        avgt   20     7.361 ±   0.273   ns/op
vanillaScalaMapGet      avgt   20     6.650 ±   0.323   ns/op
```

**Memory allocation rate**

```
enumeratumScalaMapGet:·gc.alloc.rate   avgt   20  1753.262 ±  14.548  MB/sec
jEnumEnumMapGet:·gc.alloc.rate         avgt   20    ≈ 10⁻⁴            MB/sec
jEnumScalaMapGet:·gc.alloc.rate        avgt   20  1976.491 ±  70.259  MB/sec
vanillaScalaMapGet:·gc.alloc.rate      avgt   20  2190.644 ± 105.208  MB/sec
```

We note `jEnumScalaMapGet` seems to have caught up with `enumeratumScalaMapGet` since 2017, and the trivial memory allocation of `jEnumEnumMapGet`.

Benchmark source:

```
public enum JAgeGroup {
    Baby,
    Toddler,
    Teenager,
    Adult,
    Senior
}
```

and

```
import java.util
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import example.JAgeGroup
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole
import enumeratum._

object AgeGroupVanilla extends Enumeration {
  type AgeGroupVanilla = Value
  val Baby, Toddler, Teenager, Adult, Senior = Value
}

sealed trait AgeGroup extends EnumEntry

case object AgeGroup extends Enum[AgeGroup] {

  val values = findValues

  case object Baby     extends AgeGroup
  case object Toddler  extends AgeGroup
  case object Teenager extends AgeGroup
  case object Adult    extends AgeGroup
  case object Senior   extends AgeGroup

}

@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
class So60374058 {
  private val jEnumEnumMap = {
    val m: util.EnumMap[JAgeGroup, String] = new util.EnumMap(classOf[JAgeGroup])
    JAgeGroup.values().foreach(e => m.put(e, e.name()))
    m
  }

  private val jEnumScalaMap = Map(JAgeGroup.values().map(e => e -> e.name()): _*)

  private val ageGroupScalaMap = Map(AgeGroup.values.map(e => e -> e.entryName): _*)

  private val vanillaScalaMap = AgeGroupVanilla.values.map(e => e -> e.toString).toMap

  private def randomFrom[A](seq: Seq[A]): A = {
    seq(scala.util.Random.nextInt(seq.size))
  }

  private var jEnum: JAgeGroup       = _
  private var ageGroupEnum: AgeGroup = _
  private var vanillaEnum: AgeGroupVanilla.AgeGroupVanilla = _

  @Setup(Level.Trial)
  def setup(): Unit = {
    jEnum = randomFrom(JAgeGroup.values())
    ageGroupEnum = randomFrom(AgeGroup.values)
    vanillaEnum = randomFrom(AgeGroupVanilla.values.toSeq)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def jEnumEnumMapGet(bh: Blackhole): Unit = bh.consume {
    jEnumEnumMap.get(jEnum)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def jEnumScalaMapGet(bh: Blackhole): Unit = bh.consume {
    jEnumScalaMap.get(jEnum)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def enumeratumScalaMapGet(bh: Blackhole): Unit = bh.consume {
    ageGroupScalaMap.get(ageGroupEnum)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def vanillaScalaMapGet(bh: Blackhole): Unit = bh.consume {
    vanillaScalaMap.get(vanillaEnum)
  }
}
```